# Twilio <Play> Verb does not complete a 20 second wav file before the <hangup> very is executed

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

A customer of mine is facing issues with our voicemail drop feature. The recording is 21 seconds long but only the first 6 to 8 seconds are played on the recipients voicemail before the call is hung up.

The sequence of events is shown in the screenshot attached

[image]

From what it looks like, a few seconds into playing the recording, the Call Completed end point is being hit which returns a hangup verb.

Any help here is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `<Hangup/>` from your initial response?

Comment: Is it definitely the start of the recording that is recorded? How does the call get to this TwiML? Are you using answering machine detection?